# As a sequence is the n^th root of a diagonal Ramsey number R(n, n) increasing, decreasing or neither?

Tags: graph-theory

As a sequence is the n^th root R(n, n)^1/n of a diagonal Ramsey number R(n, n) increasing, decreasing or neither?

As a sequence of positive real numbers is the n^th root of a diagonal Ramsey number, bounded in [sqrt(2), 4], namely

R(n, n)^1/n

also decreasing as n --> oo if infinitely many terms of R(n, n)^1/n are in the compact set [sqrt(2), 4]?

Actually as an infinite sequence of real numbers is

R(n, n)^1/n

monotone at all (I mean either decreasing, increasing), or not monotone? If it is not monotone in some interval for infinitely many n it cannot converge. I mean there's tons of real analysis stuff on this.

A monotone increasing or monotone decreasing infinite sequence of real numbers with all or most of its terms inside a closed and bounded set converges (real analysis).

But I can find nothing on this in the graph theory literature regarding R(n, n)^1/n because the emphasis is on constructions and working with complete subgraphs K_n, and on finding finer upper bounds on the nth root of diagonal Ramsey numbers, using probabilistic methods like the Lovasz Local lemma, not on real number sequences.

I think I have shown correctly that, as n --> oo,

r(n + 1)^(1/n+1)/r(n)^1/n < 1,

but if you think this is in error or if you disagree please tell me why.

Comment: I was about to point you to some recent work that I saw on the arXiv, but it turns out that is your own paper!

Comment: There is defintely a gap in the reasoning of your paper, or at least the first version on the arXiv. If $(a_n)$ is a monotone increasing sequence, it does not follow that $(a_n^{1/n})$ is a monotone sequence

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge, and see for example [the respective Open Problems Graden page](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/diagonal_ramsey_numbers) , it is still unknown whether 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} R(n,n)^{1/n}$$ 
exists (but it seems plausible it does).

Any monotonicity result would imply the existence of this limit, as the sequence is known to be bounded (by classical results, as you mention).

Thus, also, the monotonicty question is (to the best of my knowledge) open.

I am unanware of any result directly contradicting your claim, so I do not disagree with it. 
However, it would be quite an important result, so my default stance is to be sceptical of any claims.

(ps: Please do not use this site for detailed inquiries on the correctness of your proof(s).)

Comment: I should add that I wrote this without being aware that the paper is available. Having looked at the paper I now do have an opinion on this, but not sure it is appropiate or useful to state it here. 

Answer (score 6):

It is not known that $R(n,n)^{1/n}$ is monotonic, it is not even known if $R(7,7)^{1/7}$ is smaller or bigger than $R(8,8)^{1/8}$.

If we knew that $R(7,7)^{1/7}$ is smaller than $R(8,8)^{1/8}$, then the known bound $R(7,7)\geq 205$ would imply $R(8,8)\geq 439$, whereas the best known lower bound is $R(8,8)\geq 282$.

If we knew that $R(7,7)^{1/7}$ is bigger than $R(8,8)^{1/8}$, then the known bound $R(7,7)\leq 540$ would imply $R(8,8)\leq 1326$, whereas the best known upper bound is $R(8,8)\leq 1870$.

Numbers taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem).

Note that a sequence can be convergent without being monotonic or even resembling to be monotonic.

Finally, this site is not the right forum to advertise or check your work.

Comment: That's a clever way to address the question. (For the edit, I just fixed the link.) 

Comment: @quid: Thank  you. I tried to edit as you did, with no success. I have now inserted the link directly: if you can fix it please do. Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with the link editing! Perhaps the follwing is interesting for the future: A problem arises if you insert the already percent encode url through the link insert functionality: the %27 already encodes ' , but the software wants to 'help' you and instead percent encodes the % in addition as %25 , so that you then have %2527 instead of %27)

Comment: Did not see your comment in time. You are welcome! Possibly my description helps. If not I will come back in some time (I just do not want to do it know since I am worried you might).